# Standard Deviation of a percentage change in Python

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy

I have 2 data sets. The first data set is called X has a mean value of m(X) and standard deviation of STD(X), the second set of data also has the mean value of m(Y) and standard deviation of STD(Y). I want to find out the the percentage change of data set 2 compared to data set 1 (i.e., change in averages over the old average multiplied by 100). So I have ((m(Y)−m(X))/m(X))∗100.

Now my question is, how do you take into account the standard deviation for this percentage change value (preferably in Python) in order to add it to the plot as error bars ?

Comment: please define *"percentage change of data set 2 compared to data set 1"* more precisely

Comment: your definition only includes means, and for that you already have a solution

Comment: there are metrics that describe kind of a "distance between distributions" that take both mean and std into account, e.g. the [Kullback-Leibler divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#KL_divergence_for_the_normal_distributions)

Comment: Calculating the percentage change includes the means only. However, now I want to plot these values with their error bars (derived from their standard deviations or standard errors). How can I compute those since the raw standard deviations are on a different scale now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a single definition for the quantity you are looking for, but the normal rules for estimating errors are:

- When adding or subtracting you add the absolute errors.
- When multiplying or dividing you add the relative errors.

Assuming you follow that, the error in `m(Y) - m(X)` is `std(X) + std(Y)`, which as a relative error is `(std(X) + std(Y)) / (m(Y) - m(X))`. Add the relative error in the denominator – `std(X) / m(X)` – and you have the relative error of the whole. Then multiply by the actual value if you want the error in your percentage.

Some things cancel out and the result is:

```
 100 * (std(X) + std(Y)) / m(X) + 100 * std(X) / (m(Y) - m(X))
```

Comment: Thanks @otus for your reply. When I implemented this, I started getting wired numbers for the estimated error that dont make sense. For example: with `m(X)=0.395782562659` and `m(Y)= 0.405592455839` and `STD(X)=0.115443410751` and `STD(Y)= 0.117531156174` as input for the function, the output is 1235.6702747695215

Comment: In this case, the change percentage is 2.47 and estimated error is 1235.6?

Comment: @amaatouq: `>>> mx,my,sx,sy=0.395782562659,0.405592455839,0.115443410751,0.117531156174`
`>>> 100*(sx+sy)/mx + 100*sx/(mx+my)`
`73.26994906387056`

Comment: @amaatouq, I get 2.47 +/- 73.3, as above, which seems about expected, considering what you get for the relative difference of the means if you try changing the means by their STD.

Comment: What you mean by relative error of the whole? ```(std(X) + std(Y)) / (m(Y) - m(X))``` stands for relative error of what?